# Need help finding datasheet or pinout for Toshiba TCD2907DG

Tags: datasheet, pinout, ccd

I really want to play with Toshiba TCD2907DG - this is color linear CCD sensor.
I've found a number of datasheets for other TCD*, but not this one.

I would really appreciate any reference to datasheet or pinout.

Comment: I think TCD2907 is different from other IC's in that family. Because the reply from toshiba support wing was: *"this products needs a Non Disclosure agreement to be signed and unfortunately we may not support small projects as it is support intensive part and we lack the manpower to support such projects".*

Comment: I found a datasheet of the TCD2707D http://www.datasheets.pl/image_sensors/TCD2707D.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some similar datasheets (TCD2901, TCD2905): [datasheetcatalog.net](http://search.datasheetcatalog.net/key/TCD290). The same on [datasheetarchive.com](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/).

[This](http://www.toshiba.com/taec/Catalog/Line.do?lineid=900041&familyid=900039) is the official Toshiba catalog page and they suggest you contact them for datasheet.

On this page you can find also the package numbering (you can get an idea about the similar TCD2905):

[image]

I've compared TCD2901 and TCD2905 and it seems the pinout is almost the same (pin 19 is not NC anymore on TCD2905):

[image]

Comment: I see... Tried to request it, their website is just painful. After sending request it brought me to 404 page, hopefully it was received...

Answer (score 1):

Have you contacted Toshiba?
Their [CCD website](http://www.toshiba.com/taec/Catalog/Line.do?lineid=900041&familyid=900039) states to contact [TechQuestions](http://www.toshiba.com/taec/support/techquestions/).

I wouldn't be surprised if the family has similar datasheets. I found one for the 2950 [here](http://cs.utsource.net/goods_files/pdf/15/153429_TOSHIBA_TCD2950D.pdf). I can't tell how similar it is to your 2907.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find the data-sheet you should still be able to figure out how to drive these devices from the other data-sheets.

Since it is a shift register, the pin count need not increase with increasing length, it simply takes longer to drive the images out (more pulses on the clocks).

This family of parts is designed to be pin compatible, if you need more resolution, simply swap in the device and change the drive waver-forms.  In an ideal world that is, the longer devices have heavier loading on the pins, but if you design for the largest device then you should be fine for the shortest devices.

The main differences seem to be that some devices are 3 parallel imagers and others are 3 imagers that are 2 pixels deep (3 X 10680 vs 6 X 10680).

The longer devices (2950) has additional horizontal phase taps (pins 6,7, 16,17) on top of the ones on the shorter (2905) taps (8,9,14,15).  This is simply because the larger devices has more shift register electrodes to drive and internally it's hard to get enough metal down to drive it.  Simply use a multi-meter to see if pin 17 is connect to 6 - as an example.

Most of the other signals you can wiggle and as long as you don't exceed the voltage limits, you can't hurt the device.  The output will be corrupted but it you understand what is going on you should be able to figure it out.  You do have existing data-sheets that will be very similar or identical in required waveforms.